# Apache Ignite 2.13.0 (Two MemoryPolicies have the same name: default) error using ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

My requirement is to run Ignite with ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext by setting configurations in application.yml property file.
Moreover, I tried to add MemoryPolicy but error occurred that (Data storage can be configured with either legacy (MemoryConfiguration, PersistentStoreConfiguration) or new (DataStorageConfiguration) classes, but not both)

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-auto-configurer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ignite-auto-configurer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8081
ignite:
  clientMode: true
  peerClassLoadingEnabled: true
  igniteInstanceName: test-name
  dataStorageConfiguration:
    dataRegionConfigurations:
      - persistenceEnabled: true
```

Error Logs

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.4)
............Removed some logs due to compliance Issue...........
org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[10:46:42]    __________  ________________ 
[10:46:42]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[10:46:42]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[10:46:42] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /x___/  
[10:46:42] 
[10:46:42] ver. 2.13.0#20220420-sha1:551f6ece
[10:46:42] 2022 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[10:46:42] 
[10:46:42] Ignite documentation: https://ignite.apache.org
[10:46:42] 
[10:46:42] Quiet mode.
[10:46:42]   ^-- Logging by 'JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]'
[10:46:42]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[10:46:42] 
[10:46:42] OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
[10:46:42] VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 15.0.2+7-27 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 15.0.2+7-27
[10:46:42] Configured plugins:
[10:46:42]   ^-- None
[10:46:42] 
[10:46:42] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[10:46:43] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[10:46:43,315][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%test-name] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1787)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1066)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1799)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1160)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration.ignite(IgniteAutoConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39.CGLIB$ignite$2(<generated>)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$263ded42.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39.ignite(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.poc.igniteautoconfigurer.IgniteAutoConfigurerApplication.main(IgniteAutoConfigurerApplication.java:10)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Two MemoryPolicies have the same name: default
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkDataRegionName(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:898)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkDataRegionConfiguration(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:733)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.validateConfiguration(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:632)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.start0(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:212)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.start(GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.start(GridCacheProcessor.java:631)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1784)
    ... 38 more
[10:46:43,316][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal%test-name] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1787)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1066)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1799)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1160)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration.ignite(IgniteAutoConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39.CGLIB$ignite$2(<generated>)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$263ded42.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39.ignite(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.poc.igniteautoconfigurer.IgniteAutoConfigurerApplication.main(IgniteAutoConfigurerApplication.java:10)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Two MemoryPolicies have the same name: default
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkDataRegionName(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:898)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkDataRegionConfiguration(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:733)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.validateConfiguration(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:632)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.start0(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:212)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.start(GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.start(GridCacheProcessor.java:631)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1784)
    ... 38 more
[10:46:43] Ignite node stopped OK [name=test-name, uptime=00:00:00.834]
2022-06-01 10:46:43.336  WARN 14752 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [org/apache/ignite/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/IgniteAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
2022-06-01 10:46:43.354  INFO 14752 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-01 10:46:43.380 ERROR 14752 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [org/apache/ignite/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/IgniteAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.poc.igniteautoconfigurer.IgniteAutoConfigurerApplication.main(IgniteAutoConfigurerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1135) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:331) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration.ignite(IgniteAutoConfiguration.java:99) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39.CGLIB$ignite$2(<generated>) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$263ded42.invoke(<generated>) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92c24d39.ignite(<generated>) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1787) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1066) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1799) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1721) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1160) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:578) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Two MemoryPolicies have the same name: default
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkDataRegionName(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:898) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkDataRegionConfiguration(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:733) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.validateConfiguration(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:632) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.start0(IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:212) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.start(GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.java:61) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.start(GridCacheProcessor.java:631) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1784) ~[ignite-core-2.13.0.jar:2.13.0]
    ... 38 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Set defaultDataRegionConfiguration: instead of dataRegionConfigurations:

Data Storage Configuration has an implicit default Region. The
problem is, adding a new region, also with default name.